# code signing in xcode 4: options grayed out & unavailable for Target, not so for Project. Why?

Tags: xcode4, code-signing, ad-hoc-distribution, over-the-air

I am so very tired of wrangling around with XCode 4's quirk's with regards to code signing.  In my project, I have a developer certificate and a distribution certificate.  I have 2 distribution provisioning profiles set to the distribution certificate for 2 different beta builds.  Now, for my Project Build Settings, I am able to set the Code Signing Identity to iPhone Distribution, what I would like.  All of these options are grayed out under the Target settings, however.  When I try to archive, I get a "Failed" message that tells me that the identity iPhone Distribution doesn't match any identity in any profile.  In the Code Signing window for the target build settings,  in parentheses it reads "no profiles currently match." Any ideas?  thanks in advance!

Comment: Does your bundle identifier match with one used in developer or distribution provisioning com.yourcompany.myapp

Comment: It matches, although in the apple developer portal, there is an additional alpha-numeric key in front of the rest of the app id, i.e., WFYE454L3P.com.yourcompany.myapp instead of just com.yourcompany.myapp.  I didn't see a way to change this, so I assumed it was automatically managed in XCode.

Comment: You might be on to something, though: now in the drop-down for my adhoc Code Signing Identity, i get a message that says "no profiles currently match com.yourcompany.myapp.  But the provisioning profile was clearly done made with the correct appID.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out what the issue was (so if anybody runs across this, you'll have a clue):  I had a lower-case letter in the AppID, whereas the bundle identifier had an upper-case letter.  It doesn't explain why it found the provisioning profile for the Project and not for the target, but hey, at least I got it fixed.